# Models disappearing in backbone collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have code that does this

```
class MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection

  initialize: ({some_id}) ->

    super
    @reset $.jStorage.get "mycollection:#{some_id}" # instant fetch
    console.log @length  # THE MODELS ARE THERE


my_collection = new MyCollection [], some_id: 123

console.log my_collection.length # THE MODELS ARE GONE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, backbone's initialize function takes in any params and feeds it out as the models, use `null` instead of `[]` unless you are explicitally saying, "this blank array is definitely real data you should use", or if you somehow have an instant fetch, it will break

```
new MyCollection null, some_id: 123
```

Comment: i spent about an hour on this, which for me in terms of bugs is about 2 months, and the last place i could possibly look was the backbone's constructor method, i recommend memorizing it because it's painful to not realize some simple mistake like this.